# what does this mean? KeyError: 'GC'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyerror, interactive-brokers

[image]

1. As you can see from the pic, there is no word 'GC' on this entire page but it still generates an error message showing 'GC' contains the error.

Where does this 'GC' thing coming from?

2. extra information:

a. I didn't use 'GC' as a gold futures contract anywhere in my code. I used command+F to find out any word containing GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the kernel? That solved the problem for me (as it seems like I created the variable before).